# API Call & JSON Decoding

Tags: json, swift, api, dictionary

Encountering error in trying to perform API request with subsequent JSON decoding into data field.

Objective is to query API and map data into Dictionary within app for easy query of data by country.

Here's API format, no API key required:

```
{
  "Global": {
    "NewConfirmed": 98206,
    "TotalConfirmed": 5492996,
    "NewDeaths": 3030,
    "TotalDeaths": 351576,
    "NewRecovered": 56379,
    "TotalRecovered": 2167913
  },
  "Countries": [
    {
      "Country": "Afghanistan",
      "CountryCode": "AF",
      "Slug": "afghanistan",
      "NewConfirmed": 584,
      "TotalConfirmed": 10582,
      "NewDeaths": 2,
      "TotalDeaths": 218,
      "NewRecovered": 35,
      "TotalRecovered": 1075,
      "Date": "2020-05-26T03:04:40Z"
    },
    {
      "Country": "Albania",
      "CountryCode": "AL",
      "Slug": "albania",
      "NewConfirmed": 9,
      "TotalConfirmed": 998,
      "NewDeaths": 1,..........
```

And here's are structs of data fields, which I think where my problem lies, but I'm a beginner and not sure on correct structure/formatting:

```
struct GlobalSum: Decodable {
    let globalNC: Int
    let globalTC: Int
    let globalND: Int
    let globalTD: Int
    let globalNR: Int
    let globalTR: Int
    let sumByCntry: [CountrySum]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case globalNC = "NewConfirmed"
        case globalTC = "TotalConfirmed"
        case globalND = "NewDeaths"
        case globalTD = "TotalDeaths"
        case globalNR = "NewRecovered"
        case globalTR = "TotalRecovered"
        case sumByCntry = "Countries"
    }
}

struct CountrySum: Decodable {
    let Country: String
    let CountryCode: String
    let Slug: String
    let NewConfirmed: Int
    let TotalConfirmed: Int
    let NewDeaths: Int
    let TotalDeaths: Int
    let NewRecovered: Int
    let TotalRecovered: Int
    let Date: String

}
```

Here's API call and JSON decode:

```
func getSummary() {
        let callString = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary"
        let urlCall = URL(string: callString)
        guard urlCall != nil else {
            print("Error reaching API")
            return
        }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlCall!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let sumPull = try decoder.decode(GlobalSum.self, from: data!)
                    print(sumPull.globalNC)
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)               }
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

And here is error:

```
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Apologies for probably obvious blunders.  Just getting started with self-educating on Swift.

Comment: please post full json ?

Comment: Paste your JSON into https://app.quicktype.io

Comment: The endpoint currently returns "You have reached maximum request limit.", and that is indeed invalid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i get from json .. your modal should be like this

```
 struct CoronaCases {
        let global : GlobalSum
        let countries: CountrySum
        let date: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case global = "Global"
            case countries = "Countries"
            case date = "Date"

        }
    }

    struct GlobalSum: Decodable {
        let globalNC: Int
        let globalTC: Int
        let globalND: Int
        let globalTD: Int
        let globalNR: Int
        let globalTR: Int


        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case globalNC = "NewConfirmed"
            case globalTC = "TotalConfirmed"
            case globalND = "NewDeaths"
            case globalTD = "TotalDeaths"
            case globalNR = "NewRecovered"
            case globalTR = "TotalRecovered"

        }
    }
    struct CountrySum: Decodable {
        let Country: String
        let CountryCode: String
        let Slug: String
        let NewConfirmed: Int
        let TotalConfirmed: Int
        let NewDeaths: Int
        let TotalDeaths: Int
        let NewRecovered: Int
        let TotalRecovered: Int
        let Date: String

    }
```

And then

```
let sumPull = try decoder.decode(CoronaCases.self, from: data!)
```

and here is what generated by app.quicktype.io

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let global: Global
    let countries: [Country]
    let date: Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case global = "Global"
        case countries = "Countries"
        case date = "Date"
    }
}

// MARK: - Country
struct Country: Codable {
    let country, countryCode, slug: String
    let newConfirmed, totalConfirmed, newDeaths, totalDeaths: Int
    let newRecovered, totalRecovered: Int
    let date: Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case country = "Country"
        case countryCode = "CountryCode"
        case slug = "Slug"
        case newConfirmed = "NewConfirmed"
        case totalConfirmed = "TotalConfirmed"
        case newDeaths = "NewDeaths"
        case totalDeaths = "TotalDeaths"
        case newRecovered = "NewRecovered"
        case totalRecovered = "TotalRecovered"
        case date = "Date"
    }
}

// MARK: - Global
struct Global: Codable {
    let newConfirmed, totalConfirmed, newDeaths, totalDeaths: Int
    let newRecovered, totalRecovered: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case newConfirmed = "NewConfirmed"
        case totalConfirmed = "TotalConfirmed"
        case newDeaths = "NewDeaths"
        case totalDeaths = "TotalDeaths"
        case newRecovered = "NewRecovered"
        case totalRecovered = "TotalRecovered"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your model like this and try parsing it. Here is my code.

Here is the correct structure:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Summary: Codable {
    let global: Global
    let countries: [Country]
    let date: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case global    = "Global"
        case countries = "Countries"
        case date      = "Date"
    }
}

struct Country: Codable {
    let country, countryCode, slug: String
    let newConfirmed, totalConfirmed, newDeaths, totalDeaths: Int
    let newRecovered, totalRecovered: Int
    let date: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case country        = "Country"
        case countryCode    = "CountryCode"
        case slug           = "Slug"
        case newConfirmed   = "NewConfirmed"
        case totalConfirmed = "TotalConfirmed"
        case newDeaths      = "NewDeaths"
        case totalDeaths    = "TotalDeaths"
        case newRecovered   = "NewRecovered"
        case totalRecovered = "TotalRecovered"
        case date           = "Date"
    }
}

struct Global: Codable {
    let newConfirmed, totalConfirmed, newDeaths, totalDeaths: Int
    let newRecovered, totalRecovered: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case newConfirmed   = "NewConfirmed"
        case totalConfirmed = "TotalConfirmed"
        case newDeaths      = "NewDeaths"
        case totalDeaths    = "TotalDeaths"
        case newRecovered   = "NewRecovered"
        case totalRecovered = "TotalRecovered"
    }
}
```

Here's API call and JSON decode:

```swift
func getSummary() {
    let callString = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary"
    let urlCall = URL(string: callString)
    guard urlCall != nil else {
        print("Error reaching API")
        return
    }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlCall!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let sumPull = try decoder.decode(Summary.self, from: data!)
                print(sumPull.global)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```